# Bash 4+: Checking whether a key-value-pair within an assoc array has been set

Tags: bash

I want to check whether a certain key-value-pair within an associative array in a Bash script has been set or not.

My code so far (example only):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A aa
aa[FIRST[SECOND]]=1

if [ ! -z ${aa[FIRST[SECOND]]+x} ]; then
    echo "Yes, value is ${aa[FIRST[SECOND]]}."
else
    echo "No, the item has not been set yet."
fi
```

To me this seems save and sound, but before submitting pivotal scripts to a core community elsewhere I thought it'd be a good idea to ask the cracks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit shorter :)

```
 if [[ ${aa[FIRST[SECOND]]+x} ]]; then ...
```

i.e. assuming key to be a string "FIRST[SECOND]"

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `bash` 4.3, you can use the `-v` operator.

```
if [ -v aa[FIRST[SECOND]] ]l; then
    echo "Yes, value is ${aa[FIRST[SECOND]]}"
else
    echo "No, the item has not been set yet."
fi
```